# saving the options selected in quiz and checking

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I have generated a quiz with questions on the same page.I want to save the answers to check with the answers in the database .How can I do it ? Below is the code for how I generated quiz.How to store the selected answer and check?

```
    <?php   for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)//loop for extracting question and options
                {?>
    <form action = "CHECK.php" method="POST">
<?PHP   
$sql = "SELECT QUESTION FROM T_QUESTIONS WHERE QUES_NO=$i LIMIT 1";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>QUESTION  $i :</th>";
                 echo "</tr>";


                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['QUESTION'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

          }
                   echo "</table>";
                   mysqli_free_result($result);

    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

 ?>
    <?PHP   
        $s = "select OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3,OPTION4,OPTION5,CORRECT_ANSWER from T_QUESTIONS where QUES_NO='$i'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
            if(!mysqli_query($conn,$s))
                echo mysqli_error($conn);
            else
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        ?>


                        <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION1']; ?>" /> A. <?php echo $row['OPTION1']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION2']; ?>" /> B. <?php echo $row['OPTION2']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION3']; ?>" /> C. <?php echo $row['OPTION3']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION4']; ?>" /> D. <?php echo $row['OPTION4']."<br>"; ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="choice<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['OPTION5']; ?>" /> E. <?php echo $row['OPTION5']."<br>"; ?>
                        <br>

        <?php  
        }       
        }
        ?>
        </form>

<button style ="color:red;border radius:10px;margin:100px;height:100px;width:200px;font-size:30px"> <a href=CHECK.php>SUBMIT TEST</a></button>
```

Correct_OPTION is in the same table that of question and options.

Comment: i dont know php well enough to contribute code, but my assumption would be to write code where you have the value of the answer and an if loop to where if the input answer = the value in db then score + 1, else score - one.

Comment: The values get passed as POST variables so you can access them using `$_POST['choice1']` which would equal the `value`. Then just compare with you DB. You should wrap all questions in the same single form tag though.

Comment: $CHOICE="choice".$i."<br>"; 
I have added this in the above code and the next page contains:<?php
$t1=$_POST['CHOICE'];
?>
<br><?php echo $t1;"<br>"?><br>
GIVING THE BLANK PAGE.WHAT CAN BE DONE

Comment: Thomas Byy Can u please describe a little more.Its not working